# trigger a synchronous call inside loop wait till two api calls get success then next iteration need to starts in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs, angular6

Tried with below code not wait for post call success jumping to next iteration before response comes.
Requirement:Need to have next iteration after the success of two api(POST/PATCH) calls

```
 for (item of data) {
  A(item)

}
A(value) {
  const resp = this.post(url, {
      'rationale': value['rationale']
    })
    .mergeMap(tempObj => {
      value['detail'] = tempObj['id']
      return this.patch(url, value['extid'], value)
    })
    .subscribe()
}
```

Comment: I think it cant be possible instead of that u can only save the observables in an array and subscribe to it after the for.

Comment: @anthony willis muñoz Could you please help me with example syntax

Comment: are you able to call .then(...) off of .subscribe()? like .subscribe().then( // do some stuff // ) cause I'd imagine that's where we'd manually iterate to the next item (if applicable) we want to check.

Comment: @Kyle Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have used the `toPromise` function with angular http to turn an observable into a promise. If you have the outer loop inside an async function, this may work:

```
// This must be executed inside an async function
for (item of data) {
  await A(item)
}

async A(value) {
  const resp = await this.post(url, {
      'rationale': value['rationale']
    })
    .mergeMap(tempObj => {
      value['detail'] = tempObj['id']
      return this.patch(url, value['extid'], value)
    }).toPromise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `from` to emit the items of an array. Use `concatMap` to map to an Observable and only map to the next one when the previous completed.

```
const resp$ = from(data).pipe(
  concatMap(value => this.post(url, { 'rationale': value['rationale'] }).pipe(
    switchMap(tempObj => {
      value['detail'] = tempObj['id']
      return this.patch(url, value['extid'], value)
    })
  ))
)
```

I used `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap` to indicate that the feature of `mergeMap` to run multiple Observables simultaneously isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit$.next(form.value)" ...
```

In your component:

```
submit$= new Subject();

ngOnInit {
submit$.pipe(
        exhaustMap(value => 
            this.post(url, {'rationale': value.rationale}))
            .pipe(concatMap( response => {
                value.detail = response.id;
                return this.patch(url, value.extid, value);
        }))).subscribe(); // rember to handle unsubcribe
}
```

The reason I use exhaustMap generally post and path are mutating calls, so that operator ensures first submit is process  ignore the rest while processing AKA avoid double submit

An even better way is using ngrx effects, which if you dont know it yet I recomend to learn it

```
submit$ = createEffect(
() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(FeatureActions.submit),
    exhaustMap( ({value}) => // if action has value property
            this.post(url, { rationale : value.rationale}))
            .pipe(concatMap( response => {
                value.detail = response.id;
                return this.patch(url, value.extid, value);
        })),
    map(result => FeatureActions.submitSuccess(result))
)
);
```